# Есть ли тут речевые ошибки?

Tags: грамотная-речь, тавтология, разговорная-речь, речевая-избыточность

*За изложение мне поставили тройку, за сочинение тоже выставили тройку.*

Смущает слово "**тоже**", получается, что поставили = выставили, но можно ли так говорить?

Comment: Равно без пробелов пишется? Просто даже в математических примерах с пробелом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вполне. В Большом толковом словаре под редакцией Кузнецова одно из значений слова "выставить" является "поставить".

1.
Поставить, вынести наружу, за пределы чего-л.
В. цветы на воздух. В. шкаф в коридор. В. пчёл на пасеку (из зимнего помещения).
2.
Вынуть, удалить что-л. вставленное.
В. рамы.
3.
разговорно-сниженное Вы́гнать, грубо удалить откуда-л.
В. за дверь, за ворота. В. из дома. Выставлю отсюда в два счёта!
4.
Выдвинуть вперёд какую-л. часть тела.
В. грудь, живот. В. ногу вперёд.
5.
Поставить перед кем-л.; предъявить кому-л., выдвинуть обычно для публичного обозрения, официального рассмотрения и т.п..
В. на стол угощение. В. свои картины на продажу. В. многочисленную армию. В. счёт. В. на аукцион сумму в миллион долларов. В. на выборах чью-л. кандидатуру. В. правительству какие-л. требования. На стенде выставлены книжные новинки.
6.
Расставить для охраны, обороны и т.п.
В. караул, посты, охрану. В. часовых.
7.
разговорное Представить, показать каким-л. образом обычно отрицательно; подчеркнуть, выделить какие-л. свойства, явления и т.п. обычно негативные.
В. в самом непривлекательном, смешном виде. В. себя мучеником. В. кого-л. дураком, подлецом. В. недостатки, слабости кого-л. В. смешные комические стороны чего-л. В. на позор, на посмешище перед кем-л..
**8.
Поставить.
В. дату. В. отметки в классном журнале. В. высший бал.**

Answer (score 2):

Говорить так, конечно, можно – кто ж запретит? А вот с точки зрения строгого подхода к формулировкам, особенно в письменной речи, выходит, что в данном случае всё же есть речевые ошибки. К ним относится тавтология:

1. Употребление однокоренных слов: ***поставили*** и ***выставили***.
2. Повтор одного и того же слова: ***тройку***.

К речевым ошибкам также можно отнести *однообразие* в составлении предложений.

[**Типы и виды речевых ошибок в русском языке: примеры и исправления**](https://kakgovorit.ru/rechevye-oshibki)

Comment: Повтор за ошибку не считаю, так что это сразу отметаем. Интересует только тождественность/псевдотождественность понятий.

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна Вы не считаете, другие считают. Тождественность есть – это зафиксировано словарями: *выставить оценку = поставить оценку*, но это слова однокоренные, что тоже нежелательно использовать не только в одном предложении, но и в соседних. // Скажите, пожалуйста, откуда это предложение? Может, в тесте предлагается? Если да, то однозначно в нём есть речевые ошибки.

Comment: Жить жизнью, писать письма, в конце концов - тавтологии на каждом шагу, так что в данном случае согласиться с вами не могу.

Comment: Нет. Это писал учитель в комментарии к работе моей дочери. Они постоянно используют развернутые конструкции (без сокращений). Я просто подредактировала предложение, заменив местоимение.

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна  Нет, ваши примеры тавтологии "законны", они устоялись в языке, как и многие плеоназмы (особенно для усиления эмоционального восприятия текста).

Comment: Есть анафора, эпифора и просто лексический повтор. Тоже скажете, что они "вне закона"?

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна Всё это способствует выразительности речи. А комментарий учителя вашей дочери грешит избыточностью, однообразностью. Он больше похож на устную речь. Короче, на письме это выглядит, мягко говоря, не очень. Что мешало написать просто: *За изложение и сочинение поставили тройки.*

Answer (score 1):

*За изложение мне **поставили** тройку, за сочинение тоже **выставили** три.*

Возможно, замена глагола связана с стилистикой, то есть выражено **недовольство** поставленной оценкой.

Из словаря:

**ВЫСТАВИТЬ,** 7. **разговорное** Представить, показать каким-л. образом обычно отрицательно; подчеркнуть, выделить какие-л. свойства, явления и т.п. обычно негативные.

Comment: По вашему мнению, тут есть ошибка?

Comment: Нет ошибки. Однокоренные? А здесь усиление значения. Такой повтор тавтологией не считают. Сравним: За изложение мне поставили тройку, за сочинение – тоже. Никаких эмоций, одна информация. Многое зависит от коммуникативности сообщения (кому и зачем пишем), только в этом плане можно оценивать предложение. А то всей художественной и разговорной речи можно придать вялость и безжизненность, ссылаясь на тавтологию.

Answer (score 0):

Примеры фраз (из нацкорпуса), в которых слово «тоже» имеет значение «заодно», «разом», «до кучи»:
Я позвал горничных женщин и с помощью их вынес бесчувственную Марью Виссарионовну; Пионову тоже вывели в двои руки. [А. Ф. Писемский. Виновата ли она? (1855)]
В 6 часов Аля вылезла, дала мне простоквашу, Тише что-то тоже выдала, после чего стала заниматься (в 6-й раз). [Е. А. Мравинский. Записки на память: Дневники. 1918--1987 (1976)]
И чтоб все выходили, а то все утонут. Все вышли и кукол тоже вынесли. [Б. С. Житков. Что я видел (1937)]

За изложение мне поставили тройку и за сочинение тоже влепили тройку с минусом.

В этих примерах нет равенства значений «вынес – вывели», «дала – выдала», «вышли – вынесли», «поставили – влепили».

Фраза «за изложение мне поставили тройку, за сочинение тоже выставили тройку» содержит две речевые ошибки. Первая (уже отмечена в вопросе) заключается в том, что, как следует из контекста, слово «тоже» здесь ложно указывает на тождественность или близость по значению лексем «поставили» и «выставили». Вторая ошибка – многословие. Исправив вторую ошибку, мы заодно избавимся и от первой:
"За изложение мне поставили тройку, за сочинение – тоже".